# Remove UITextView extra border

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uitextview, border

I've made a `UITextView` yet there's some unwanted spacing:

[image: black border]

(I'm drawing the white box separately). I'm fairly certain I got the coordinates right since if I scroll it gets cut off at the right places:

[image: scrolled to show bounds]

How can I make the text be drawn further to the left, and also to have the top-most position be further on the top? That is, I'd like it to look like this:

[image: desired outcome]

I've tried `[[textView layer] setBorderWidth:0.0f]`, but to no avail - it already doesn't have a border. This is what it looks like if I set the border width to 2 and to the color red:

[image: with layer red border]

I'm curious where the extra spacing is coming from and how to control it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried experimenting with textContainerInset?

According to the [docs at developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html), "This property provides text margins for text laid out in the text view."  This is new in iOS 7.

Comment: If your developing for iOS 7.0 or greater that's the way to go. Works perfect!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the following does the trick:

```
UITextView *textView = ...;
[textView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10, -8, 0, 0)];
```

The result is exactly as I wanted it to be. This isn't too satisfying as it uses magic numbers, so if anyone has a better answer, feel free to comment or answer.